# <f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I got this error when I upgraded from primefaces 3.0.M3 to 3.0.M4-SNAPSHOT

> @60,114  Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@1d9c3e7

I understand that it is happening in other libraries like icefaces too, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PrimeFaces tags/components are not been parsed at all and thus treated as plain HTML which caused that the real closest parent JSF component is a `<h:form>`.

This can have at least 2 causes:

1. You didn't [update](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1431) the taglib namespace URI from `http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui` to the new namespace `http://primefaces.org/ui` which was introduced in M4.
2. The PrimeFaces 3.0 M4 JAR file isn't in the webapp's runtime classpath. Verify if this is done right. This is to be achieved by dropping the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`, or if it's been dropped elsewhere, by including it in *Deployment Assembly* list in project's properties (assuming that you're using Eclipse).